# How to treat losses asymmetrically in Keras?

Tags: keras, loss-function

I am developing a Keras NN that predicts three categories: A, B and C. However, the impact of errors is not symmetrical. i.e. If the network predicts A when the label is C, that is much less desirable than predicting C when the label is A.

How can I weight different errors differently depending on the predictions?

Another simple example. Do I need to take an umbrella when I go out? If it rains, it's important that I take the umbrella. If it doesn't rain, it isn't particularly important whether I take the umbrella or not. i.e. False positives are worse than false negatives.

Thank you for any hints or examples.

Comment: Harrell explicitly addresses carrying an umbrella! https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ The key is, in some sense, not to do classification at all, but to deal with the probability outputs.